# Opening a saved workbook causes the current workbook to throw exceptions

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to open a save Excel workbook while keeping a reference to the current workbook. The issue is that as soon as I open the saved workbook, the original throws an exception upon access.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate. I put this in an event handler for a ribbon button to test it.

```
try
{
    string workbookPath = @"C:\Temp\Test.xlsx";
    Workbook current = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
    Workbook newWorkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);

    current.Activate();                   // throws an exception
    Sheets sheets = current.Worksheets;   // throws an exception
    string name = current.Name;           // throws an exception
}
catch (Exception ex) {}
```

If you debug and put watches on the `current`, `sheets` and `name` variables you can see that as soon as `newWorkbook` is instantiated, the other variables thrown exceptions when accessed.

The exception that's thrown is

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was caught
  Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401A8
  Source=WorkbookTest
  ErrorCode=-2147221080
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.Activate()
       at WorkbookTest.Ribbon1.button1_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) in C:\Temp\WorkbookTest\WorkbookTest\Ribbon1.cs:line 25
  InnerException:
```

The strangest thing is that this **only** happens on a fresh instance of Excel. If I open Excel, close the first workbook and open a new one, it works just fine. It's only if I have a newly opened instance of Excel that this fails. I really don't understand why that is.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: What is Current set to after you set it to ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: @DougGlancy I'm not sure what you mean. It's set to the active workbook. "Book1" by default. It's a Workbook object.

Comment: That's what I meant.  Sometimes the addin is the activebook right when it starts, although I didn't thinks so here, since you were calling from a button.  Worth a shot though.

Comment: @DougGlancy Ah okay. Good to check, I didn't know about that.

Comment: I think this might be the correct behaviour. If you were to manually start a new Excel session (which automatically creates a new workbook [Book1]) and then, without doing anything to Book1 open an existing workbook, you'll notice that Book1 no longer exists in the Excel session. I'm guessing you're experiencing the same behaviour via your C# add-in.

Comment: @creamyegg Wow, that actually makes a ton of sense. I didn't even think about that at all. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @root45 cool, glad I could help. I've now posted my comment as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. How do you handle it? Catch it and then create the new "current" workbook again?

Comment: nm, found an easy work around. I created a method to try to check if a workbook is still around. if not I recreate the current workbook.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this might be the correct behaviour.

If you were to manually start a new Excel session (which automatically creates a new workbook [Book1]) and then, without doing anything to Book1 open an existing workbook, you'll notice that Book1 no longer exists in the Excel session.

I'm guessing you're experiencing the same behaviour via your C# add-in.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behavior as described by 'creamyegg'

Excel will discard the temporary workbook if it is not used.  To get around this problem you just need to use the sheet before opening another.

Find an empty cell and modify it!  Your workbook will remain and you can go about your business. :)